# BigDecimal division is rounding up

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm trying to calculate the following:

```
(1 - (1/365)) * (1 - (2/365) = 0.99727528617
```

I would like to store the entire decimal. Here is my code, but it is giving me an answer of 1:

```
public BigDecimal probability(int t){
    BigDecimal probT; // holds our probability of a single (1-(t/365))
    BigDecimal result; // holds our result
    result = BigDecimal.ONE; // initialize result to 1

    // for 1 to t-1
    for (int n = 1; n < t; n++){            
        int numerator = n; // numerator the value of n

        int denominator = 365; // denominator 365 

        // numberator / denominator (round down)
        probT = BigDecimal.valueOf(numerator).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(denominator), RoundingMode.DOWN);

        // 1-answer
        probT = BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(probT);

        // multiply the probabilities together 
        result = result.multiply(probT);

    }
    return result;
}

BigDecimal ans2 = bc.probability(3);
System.out.println("P(3) = " + ans2.toString());
```

Output:

```
P(3) = 1
```

Comment: Do note that generally speaking, it is not possible to store the *entire* decimal representation of a quotient, because few quotients have a finite decimal representation.  In the general case, you need to decide somehow how much of the decimal expansion you want.  In `BigDecimal` terms, that means choosing the scale you want for the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the division you are computing is made with a scale of 0. Quoting the method [`divide(divisor, roundingMode)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-java.math.RoundingMode-) Javadoc:

> Returns a `BigDecimal` whose value is `(this / divisor)`, and whose scale is `this.scale()`.

In this case, `this.scale()` refers to the scale of the numerator, which is 0 because the numerator is `BigDecimal.valueOf(n)`, with `n` being an integer.

You need to change this division to use [`divide(divisor, scale, roundingMode)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-int-java.math.RoundingMode-) instead and specify the scale you want.

Answer (score 2):

From the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

> When a MathContext object is supplied with a precision setting of 0
>   (for example, MathContext.UNLIMITED), arithmetic operations are exact,
>   as are the arithmetic methods which take no MathContext object. (This
>   is the only behavior that was supported in releases prior to 5.)
>
> As a corollary of computing the exact result, the rounding mode
>   setting of a MathContext object with a precision setting of 0 is not
>   used and thus irrelevant. In the case of divide, the exact quotient
>   could have an infinitely long decimal expansion; for example, 1
>   divided by 3.
>
> If the quotient has a nonterminating decimal expansion and the
>   operation is specified to return an exact result, an
>   ArithmeticException is thrown. Otherwise, the exact result of the
>   division is returned, as done for other operations.

To fix, you need to do something like this:

```
   // numberator / denominator (round down)
        probT = BigDecimal.valueOf(numerator).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(denominator), 10,RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

where 10 is precision(decimal places precision) and RoundingMode.DOWN is rounding mode